# Rust Cargo build and crosscompile for specific CPU

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I want to compile two binaries for different target architectures (eg. Skylake and Sandy Bridge).
These are usually two lengthy cargo commands:

> RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=skylake" cargo build --target
> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --release

How can I set up cargo to build both binaries (with different names) from the same main.rs automatically?
Ideally in either the `config.toml` or the `Cargo.toml` so I can add it to a repository.

Comment: Why not just create a `build.sh` that runs both commands?

Comment: I could do that, but that doesn't feel like good practice. Especially since build targets are usually specified in the Cargo.toml

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but the arch module has docu for [dynamic CPU-feature detection](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/index.html#dynamic-cpu-feature-detection) to avoid creating multiple binaries.

Comment: @maxy interesting. But for now I'll trust the compiler to optimize based on the target arch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following text to your `config.toml`:

```
[build]
target = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustflags = ["-C","target-cpu=skylake"]

[profile.dev]   #do not need to add `--release` now
opt-level = 3
debug = false
debug-assertions = false
overflow-checks = false
lto = false
panic = 'unwind'
incremental = false
codegen-units = 16
rpath = false
```

But it seems like it can't compile for two different target architectures with one `config.toml`, so you may have to create two `config.toml` and use `cargo --manifest-path PATH/TO/CONFIG` to compile two binaries separately.